# React Hooks seacrh input keypress enter redirect result page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, react-hooks

I have a search component. When input keypress enter redirect to result page. But I can't get search filtered results. How can I get filtered json? Here is the code can anyone help me?

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-swanson-t8fi1

Comment: remove keypress handler if you do not want to redirect on keypress

Comment: @NileshPatel no i want redirect, but i want get filtered results in result page

Comment: Since there is no parent child relationship between the comps you filter the data and navigate then, you need to use context or redux to save the game obect ids you queried, retrieve them on `SearchResult` comp and then filter data.

Comment: @kboul how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add this to your routes. Because you only have declared `SearchResult` route not `SearchResultPage` regardless they use the same comp

```
{
    path: `/SearchResultPage`,
    component: SearchResult
  }
```

Setup context:

```
export const Context = createContext();
```

and Provider:

```
const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [gameIds, setGameIds] = useState([]);
  const provider = useMemo(() => ({ gameIds, setGameIds }), [
    gameIds,
    setGameIds
  ]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ ...provider }}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

to be able to save variables globally.

save the ids into an array on search comp:

```
const { setGameIds } = useContext(Context);

...
setGames(gameData);
setSearch(e.target.value);
setGameIds(gameData.map(({ id }) => id));
```

retrieve them on `SearchResult`

```
const { gameIds } = useContext(Context);
...
data.filter(({ id }) => gameIds.includes(id))
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hwo-to-retrieve-filter-result-in-another-route-g6z40)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, when there is no result can I show other div?

Comment: Yes. Use the ternary operator f.i `gameIds.length === 0 ? 'show a message' : what you already doing`... or if, else whatever suits you best.

Comment: Can I ask another question for this component?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of how it works [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-carson-e63r5). Of course, you would need to refactor the code.

Idea is that you need to pass search word in query param of URL when you press the key:

```
history.push(`/SearchResult/?search=${search}`);
```

On this page, you need to get param from URL and with `useLocation`:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

And parse results with URLSearchParams:

```
const search = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("query");
```

Please check more details in the provided example.

Comment: thanks your answer. I could not fully understand, in route.js you are import querystring. But how can i get this?

Comment: I don't use Routre.js anymore. If you check code you would see that it is not used anywhere in code